# Stripe create a customer and recurring charge in PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I have a website where I want to integrate the Stripe payment gateway, when a user registers I want to create a customer on Stripe and charge them the first month fee for example $100 and from the next month I want to charge them $50.

How do I create the customer and then charge them simultaneously and setup recurring payment, so far I could only reach find out about one time payment system:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
    array(
        "amount" => $amount,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "source" => $token,
        "description" => $email
    )
);
```

For recurring payments, will I have to run this code in a cron or is there any better way ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I used the following code to create a customer first and then charge that customer with their charge id:

```
//Create Customer:
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'source'   => $token,
    'email'    => $_POST['email'],
    'plan'     => "monthly_recurring_setupfee",
));

// Charge the order:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'customer'    => $customer->id,
    "amount" => $amount,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "description" => "monthly payment",
    )
);
```

this seems to be working.

Another question: I have created two plans `monthly_recurring_setupfee` and `monthly_recurring`, the previous plan contains the amount that I want to charge plus the one time setup fee and the later plan contains the regular amount that I will be charging from the second month, I was thinking of assigning the user the `monthly_recurring_setupfee` plan at the time of registration and if the payment is successful change the plan of the user to `monthly_recurring`, is this possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to create a customer, register them to a plan and charge them a one-time setup fee. Here is the code that I have used:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            'source'   => $token,
            'email'    => $billing_email,
            'plan'     => $stripePlan,
            'account_balance' => $setupFee,
            'description' => "Charge with one time setup fee"
            ));
```

This will charge them a one time set up fee `'account_balance' => $setupFee,`, register them to a plan and charge them the amount of the plan.

[Stripe one-time subscription fee](https://support.stripe.com/questions/subscription-setup-fees)

Comment: Do you know if the existence of the `plan` parameter for customer creation is documented anywhere?

Answer (score 5):

To charge a customer for the same price each month you need to use Stripe's [subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions). If you subscribe a customer to a $50 monthly plan he will be charged automatically each month for $50 without any manual work from you.

As for the setup fee of $50 for the first month, what you need is too look at [Invoice Items](https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#adding-invoice-items).

Here's the flow you would follow:

1. Create the customer using the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).
2. Create the $50 Invoice Item through the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem).
3. Create the subscription to the $50 monthly plan using the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription).

The last step automatically creates the first invoice for the subscription and adds the invoice item to it. The customer is then charged $50 for the plan and $50 for the invoice item so $100 as expected. Then next month on the same day the customer will be charged $50 only and each month from then.

Comment: won't this create two transactions from the customer, one for the invoice item and the other for plan.

Comment: @Criesto: No it won't. Invoice Items are here exactly for that. Just try this in the dashboard in Test mode and you'll see how it works

Comment: where we aare taking the card number and cvv information?

Comment: There are complete end to end guides on Stripe docs showing how to start a subscription and collect payments: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart